# Re-using same method in multiple windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, composition

I would like to ask for your help. Will you help captain newbie once again? :)

I have several windows forms where I use datagridview. I would like to format the datagridviews in the same way on all the forms (e.g. AllowUserToAddRows = false;).

To do this I created a class MYFormatting and method as below. I am going to use composition to re-use this method on multiple forms. I would be grateful if you could let tell me if my approach is correct?

```
public class MyFormating
    {
        public void FormatDGV(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dgv.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            dgv.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
            dgv.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dgv.MultiSelect = false;
        }
    }
```

When initializing new form

```
Form1 frmForm1 = new Form1(new MyFormating());
```

Then in each form I am going to call myFormat method and pass datagridview.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly MyFormating _myFormat;

    public Managers(MyFormating myFormat)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myFormat = myFormat;
        _myFormat.FormatDGV(dgvManagers);
```

---

Leaving MyFormatting class as it is and then changing my Form1 code to below would give me same result. Is this still composition? Should I do something like this or convention rather say to follow the way I described above?

When initializing new form

```
Managers frmManagers = new Managers();
```

Then in each form I am going to create new MyFormatting instance and pass datagridview to it's method

```
public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        private readonly MyFormating _myFormat;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myFormat = new MyFormating();
            myFormat.FormatDGV(dgvManagers);
```

Comment: I believe we are getting in opinion space here, as we cannot oversee your full project, I would say: Does not matter, what fits you best.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your purpose. "Extension" is a more practical method;

```
public static class UIExtensions
{
    public static void FormatDGV(this DataGridView dgv)
    {
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dgv.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgv.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dgv.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dgv.MultiSelect = false;
    }
}
```

and in your form code(onload or constructor);

```
dgvManagers.FormatDGV();
```

Look for Extension Methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a new class which inherits from DataGridView. In this class just set the propertys in the constructor as you wish. Rebuild the project and your own DataGridView should show up in the Toolbox. Just place it on the Form like you would do with the standard DataGridView.

Example for the DataGridView with predefined values:

```
public class MyDataGridView: DataGridView
{
    public MyDataGridView()
    {
        AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        RowHeadersVisible = false;
        MultiSelect = false;
    }
}
```

And also a screenshot of the custom DataGridView in Action:

[image: DataGridView in Toolbox]